# risk of using persistent cookie for loginid

Tags: javascript, tomcat, cookies, authentication

I'm wondering about how to design a spam proof site without the use of captcha, but which allows the javascript application to store a persistent cookie that holds the login id and/or username so the user doesn't always have to login.

I see that many sites have some technique for "remember me", and I don't want robots to be able to post messages as if they are some user.

I am using Tomcat and javascript/ajax.

Andy

Comment: given the current trend of paying humans to create batches of spam accounts that then get hit by bots to actually do the spam, it's virtually impossible to create a genuinely "spam proof" site. The best you can hope for is to minimise it, but you'll never be able to completely eradicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robots would need a valid account to be able to abuse a login form. And in this case it's completely irrelevant if you have a "remember me" button or not. It's just for user convenience so they don't have to login when their session (cookie) expires.

So there are absolutely no security implications if you add a (properly coded - i.e. not storing the plaintext password in a cookie or something similar) "remember me" function.